# Xamarin cross-platform user experience vs. native development

Tags: performance, user-interface, xamarin

I am trying to evaluate whether Xamarin would be a good option for my project. The project is a large, complex app for Android and iOS with a lot of client-server communication. The user interface is a major focus and has to be really fast and smooth. Also, we plan to make large use of UX graphic effects (comparable to the Spotify app).

For now we are planning to go for two separate native apps using Java/Objective-C. However, the possibility of cross-platform code sharing would be very convenient for us of course.

Most opinions I've heard so far say that Xamarin - although far better than HTML5 apps - cannot match the UX of a native app. Also, I tested the following applications made with Xamarin (on Android):

- Rdio
- MarketWatch
- Busch Gardens Discovery Guide
- Sqor
- Storyo

From my impression, none of them could quite match the speed and smoothness of a good native app.

If our focus is on a top notch user experience, would Xamarin really be a viable option? Can it really match a native UX? I am particularly looking for opinions from developers who have experience with large and complex cross-platform Xamarin applications. A few critical voices would be very helpful.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I was me asking a similar question and did the same test than you: Storyo,  snap-attack and MarketWatch. But my impressions was that it was very very smooth and didn't feel that it was not "real" native application. Can you test these applications back and maybe give us your impressions now plz ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm on the Rdio mobile development team, so I can make some personal reflections from that standpoint.

Xamarin allows you to write native applications in C#.  Any slowness, jankiness, ugliness or bad-appiness *usually* has nothing to do with the Xamarin layer itself.

You save some time being able to share core business logic between your different clients, but you're still writing the UI from scratch, specific to the platform.  You're just writing it in C#.

But while you save that time, you're spending it in other ways.  All of those SDKs you want to use probably aren't compatible with Xamarin out of the box. You won't be **pod install**'ing that iOS framework, and you might be reinventing the wheel for handfuls of things.  Xamarin takes advantage of the [NuGet repo](https://www.nuget.org/) so you have a library of components that handle many of the things most people need (Analytics, Testing, Facebook SDK, JSON parsing, Database, etc etc) but it doesn't cover everything.  And it certainly doesn't cover stuff that's out the day of an Apple or  Google product announcement.

Any 3rd party code that you do want to import into your project will be done through writing [custom bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/).  While not **usually** difficult, it is time consuming.  Xamarin has a team of people that specialize in assisting you in this. This fact speaks to the process being messy at times.

So while the slowness, jankiness, ugliness or bad-appiness probably isn't the fault of Xamarin, it might be the fault of you spending time in places you normally wouldn't, or not being able to take advantage of features you normally would.  If that 3rd party partner SDK is giving you problems, your troubleshooting may take twice as long because there's a layer that you don't control.

- UI is a wash.  You're writing it from scratch anyway.
- Business logic is shared.  Depending on the app that might be a win if you architect your application to take advantage of it.
- Compatibility / bleeding edge ability will be lacking.  That might not matter to you at all, or you might be the person wanting to take advantage of that hot new API in the next OS release the day it's announced.

My personal thought, without knowing specifics, is if you want to build an application that you plan on being around years from now, and that will take advantage of the latest and greatest, I'd tell you to write natively for each platform.  Unless you can really see huge gains in sharing that business logic the upfront gains are minimal.  Or if you really like C#.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin uses *native controls*. So you design a **fully native UI** per platform. The users can't see that your App is made with Xamarin or Java/Objective-C. 
There are sometimes performance issues in conjunction with the platform independent UI wrapper `Xamarin.Forms`. But you're not forced to use it. When you have still performance issues in your `Xamarin.Android` or `Xamarin.iOS` app then you produce them in your code.

There are benchmark results for Android apps comparing `Xamarin.Android` and `Java` apps: [Does anyone have benchmarks (code & results) comparing performance of Android apps written in Xamarin C# and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134522/does-anyone-have-benchmarks-code-results-comparing-performance-of-android-ap)

As you can see Xamarin's internal performance became better and better over the time.

Conclusion: Yes, you can write smooth native Apps using Xamarin.