# what about the performance of app developed by VS2015's xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I tried to use vs2015's xamarin to develop ios and android app, but I'm not sure of the performance, does anybody know it?

Comment: Visual studio performance is better. But the **simulator** is slow. You must attached a device for debugging/running of your application.

Comment: I mean the app developped,not the vs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin provides two technologies to deeply monitor your App performance.

**1. Xamarin Test Cloud**
Xamarin test cloud provides over 2000 real devices where you can run you application and see how your app performs at different devices.

**2. Xamarin Insights**
Xamarin insights provides help to see how end users interact with your application, see which user is logged on to your application (user identity), provides instance notification about your app crash..


Now if talk about the app performance itself, its depends on how you code and how you manage your app tasks.But as a whole, the performance is same as compared to any other native app.
Here are different suggestions and reviews about xamarin app development and performance:

[Does anyone have benchmarks (code & results) comparing performance of Android apps written in Xamarin C# and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134522/does-anyone-have-benchmarks-code-results-comparing-performance-of-android-ap)

[Xamarin cross-platform user experience vs. native development](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49938/xamarin-cross-platform-user-experience-vs-native-development)

[Native vs cross platform development1 – Performance & limitations](https://www.simform.com/blog/native-vs-cross-platform-development)

[Xamarin vs. Native App Development](http://willowtreeapps.com/blog/xamarin-vs-native-app-development/)