# For Android App c# is better or java?

Tags: java, c#, android

i want to start Android Developing. I Can Use `c#` or `Java` to start for `Android`
Developing.
I am a  `.NET` developer.
My Question is which language is better for `android` programming. which limitation these language have?
what is their power in android programming?Can I develop full apps in `.NET` without learning `java`?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134522/does-anyone-have-benchmarks-code-results-comparing-performance-of-android-ap

Comment: Yes just use Xamarin for backend and frontend do it natively. Many small and big firms are using .Net now since Xamarin output is cross platform.

Comment: Check this https://magenic.com/thinking/mobile-development-platform-performance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) if you want to develop mobile apps with c#. However, when I ask mobile developers, they prefer to write native apps.

With Xamarin you will have the option of using VS which I think is very good, but you have to consider that it is usable for develop both Android and IOS apps. You have to consider performance and size of the app.

I have to add that Xamarin is now free if you have Visual Studio 2015

So my advice in total would be:

If you need only Android or IOS: go with native

If you need both Android and IOS and it is a small company or if the budget is limited, then go with Xamarin

If not again go with native

---

There is also a project called [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) which will do the same using javascript

Comment: But you can build native Android apps with C# too. So native C# versus native Java... which is preferable?

Comment: @Matthew I remember there was a project that has been deprecated 3 years ago. Other than that the option that is right now supported by Visual Studio is basically Xamarin that has been bought by MS and integrated into the IDE. Do you know any other way?

Comment: I think that you would know better than I do as I am new to C# and merely looked up this thread so that I would understand. The reason I am confused is because of this quote: _"You can build native apps for Android, iOS, and Windows by using C# or F#_"
 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/cross-platform-mobile-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Matthew Yup. that is Xamarin that I am keep mentioning :) The answer still applies.