# Xamarin performance issues

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, mobile

I am new to Xamarin and would love to build our Android mobile solution with Xamarin, given our .NET expertise. I am interested to know if there are any performance issues or limitations we should be aware off, before we dive deeper. There are a lot of comparison for native (Java/Kotlin) development with ReactNative, Ionic etc, but not much with Xamarin, specially for Android.

Comment: This question may be a little off topic, but If you planned on using Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS their performance is on par with native and expose you to anything you'd expect to be able to do in Java/Swift/Objc but in C#. One of the few downsides I can think of is it does slightly increase [package size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/app-package-size), but even that is negligible.

Comment: Xamarin on iOS is certainly less performance than native due to compilation process. But on Android, I am not sure, if the compilation process has any impact at all

Answer (score 0):

This question does not really has a specific answer, it is a subject to debate. To answer it briefly, there is no important limitations to using Xamarin for mobile apps. It has advantages and drawbacks, and the best way to learn the is to try it.

Since Xamarin is very close to the native platforms, you won't lack any hardware access, which is a good point for a mobile framework.

In terms of performances, [this article](https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/engineering/performance-comparison-xamarin-forms-xamarin-ios-xamarin-android-vs-android-and-ios-native-applications/) gives valuable input, like several interesting benchmarks opposing Xamarin and the native solutions.

The same site also has [another article](https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/mobile/pros-and-cons-of-xamarin-vs-native/) givin more details on how to chose one or another.

From my point of view, Xamarin is a safe solution. We've been using it for 3 years now for various customers, some of them asking for very specific designs, and we never had any issue with it. It is more a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a question similiar too your's, see the next link:

[Does anyone have benchmarks (code & results) comparing performance of Android apps written in Xamarin C# and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134522/does-anyone-have-benchmarks-code-results-comparing-performance-of-android-ap)